# Full screen not available in vmplayer 6 (on Linux)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, vmware-player, fullscreen

I recently updated vmware player from 5.0.2 to 6.0.0, and now the "full screen" menu item is always grayed out. It happens with all my VMs, regardless of the guest OS. "Enter Unity" is still available for some reason.

When I edit a VM to start up in full screen it works, but once I leave full screen I can't go back, which is really annoying. I've no clue where to start looking for the cause.
I'm seeing this on Ubuntu 13.04 and OpenSUSE 12.3.

Comment: Updating to 6.0.1 doesn't solve the Problem...